# c fwrite() writing data only right one of the struct variable?

Tags: c

This function is supposed to get a parameter as the pointer of a file and put all file into the struct anagram, then write it to another file. Right now the data only contains 
a.word, but it suppose to containst a.sorted too?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "anagrams.h"


void buildDB ( const char *const dbFilename ) 
{
    FILE *dict, *anagramsFile;
    struct anagram a;

    //check if dict and anagram.data are open
    errno=0;
    dict= fopen(dbFilename, "r");

    if(errno!=0) {
        perror(dbFilename);
        exit(1);
    }

    errno=0;

    anagramsFile = fopen(anagramDB,"wb");

    char word[SIZE];
    char *pos;
    int i=0;

    while(fgets(word, SIZE, dict) !=NULL) {

        //get ripe of the '\n'
        pos=strchr(word, '\n');
        *pos = '\0';

        strncpy(a.word,word,sizeof(word));
        //lowercase word
        int j=0;
        while (word[j]) {
            tolower(word[j]);
            j++;
        }

        /* sort array using qsort functions */ 
        qsort(word,strlen(word), 1, charCompare);

        strncpy(a.sorted,word,sizeof(word));

        fwrite(&a,1,sizeof(word),anagramsFile);

        i++;
    }
    fclose(dict);
    fclose(anagramsFile);

}
```

data:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char word[SIZE];
...
fwrite(&a,1,sizeof(word),anagramsFile);
```

`sizeof(word)` returns the full size of the buffer, so you're writing the full length of the buffer each time. You'll want to use `strlen()` or similar to only write the part of the buffer you're actually using.